# Display Barcodes in SSRS reports

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have some Barcode data stored in a SQL Server table with the font `Code39-Digit` the barcodes are stored in the table as `*12312313213*`.

I am trying to create a report in SSRS with the barcodes (scanner readable).

I have tried the following two methods and got nowhere :( .

1. [`How to embed Barcodes in your SSRS report`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/789254/How-to-embed-Barcodes-in-your-SSRS-report)
2. [`.NET Barcode Generator/SDK for SSRS Tutorial`](http://www.aspper.com/barcode-reporting-services/tutorial.html)

Method 1 does not support the Barcode font Code39-Digit.

Method 2 I managed to show Barcodes in the BIDS but when I deploy the report to a server it goes all pear shape. The barcode wont show at all on the Reports Manager.

I have made sure that my Reports Server has the Font installed. but no luck so far.

I am running out of options any suggestions or pointer in the right direction are much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use [NeoDynamic Barcode Professional](http://www.neodynamic.com/products/barcode/cri-ssrs-reporting-services/)  It works well for what you are trying to do and offers other features.

Comment: let me try the free version :)

Comment: The add-on looks good and it works too, I have deployed the report and it is showing the barcodes as expected :) , do you know how much you paid for it ?

Comment: I don't know which tier we paid for, Sorry.

Answer (score 4):

Inside the report, use any text controller (like TextBox for example). 
set it's font property to "typereader":
textBox -> Properties -> font -> FontFamily - Typereader 39.
Make sure you got font 39 in your computer, and that's it.
[image]